# Facebook Connect w/ MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I am trying to add facebook connect into my ASP.NET MVC I followed all the directions on how to do this, however it isn't working right for some reason.

In IE the window that prompts you to login is blank but in Firefox or Safari it works fine.. anyone have any insight to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually indicates misconfigured connect url (or xd receiver url, check out your server logs for 404).

I had some similar problem when I set up a Connect-app. I had set the url to example.com without the leading **www**.example.com. This made the whole app act really weird when I used "www".

So, check your configuration one more time...

Another possible solution:
IE has security zones. Internet, Intranet, ... etc

Each of these zones have different level of security settings. One of these settings is "Enable Protected Mode".

Try by enabling protected mode in Intranet zone too.

Comment: Thanks yep that is exactly what it was, I was testing on localhost and thats where it doesn't work 100% stable.. so I tested it on a remote hoste and it works fine